# How to do multiple input with streamio-ffmpeg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, sidekiq

I would like to recreate this ffmpeg line (which works well) in my rails app :

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0] [1] afir=dry=10:wet=10' output.wav
```

So here is my config:

```
module EncodingConstants
  PROCESSED_DEFAULTS = {
    resolution:           '500x400',
    video_codec:          'libx264',
    constant_rate_factor: '30',
    frame_rate:           '25',
    audio_codec:          'aac',
    audio_bitrate:        '128k',
    audio_sample_rate:    '48000',
    progress: :processing_progress
  }.freeze

  AUDIO_EFFECTS = {
    multi_effect: %w[-i /home/yozuu/2.mp4 -filter_complex [0] [1] afir=dry=10:wet=10]
 }.freeze
```

So Sidekiq send this back to me :

```
I, [2020-08-12T19:40:38.828081 #2142]  INFO -- : Running transcoding...
["/sbin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/home/yozuu/labo/video-project/tmp/1597254011-2142-0001-8820/1.mp4", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-acodec", "aac", "-s", "500x282", "-i", "/home/yozuu/2.mp4", "-filter_complex", "'[0]", "[1]", "afir=dry=10:wet=10'", "-r", "25", "-b:a", "128k", "-ar", "48000", "-aspect", "1.7730496453900708", "/home/yozuu/labo/video-project/tmp/1597254011-2142-0001-8820/1.mp4"]

E, [2020-08-12T19:40:38.897575 #2142] ERROR -- : Failed encoding...
["/sbin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/home/yozuu/labo/video-project/tmp/1597254011-2142-0001-8820/1.mp4", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-acodec", "aac", "-s", "500x282", "-i", "/home/yozuu/2.mp4", "-filter_complex", "'[0]", "[1]", "afir=dry=10:wet=10'", "-r", "25", "-b:a", "128k", "-ar", "48000", "-aspect", "1.7730496453900708", "/home/yozuu/labo/video-project/tmp/1597254011-2142-0001-8820/1.mp4"]


.....

Unknown decoder 'libx264'

Errors: no output file created.
```

I don't understand why because for me the command line ffmpeg seems correct.
Anyone have a idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: It is invalid command line, -vcodec libx264 and -acodec aac should be all after last -i.

Comment: Yeah, but how to put them after the second input ?

Comment: Ask ruby-on-rails sidekiq devs, have nothing much directly with ffmpeg.